# In R using highcharteR package how to change background color?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

This is my highchart code chart using R

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
library(gapminder)


hchart(gapminder::gapminder,
       "column",
       backgroundColor = 'red',
       
       hcaes(x = year, y = lifeExp, size = pop),
       colorByPoint = TRUE)
```

I checked here [backgroundColor Highcharts Doc](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/backgroundcolor-color/) and its look like its the right way to change the background color but its not working.

Any help?

Comment: try piping your highchart into `hc_theme(chart = list(backgroundColor = "red"))`

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen I did this and didnt work: `hchart(gapminder::gapminder,
       "column",
        
       hcaes(x = year, y = lifeExp, size = pop),
       colorByPoint = TRUE)%>%
    
    hc_theme(chart = list(backgroundColor = "red"))`

Comment: needed `hc_add_theme()` - see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hc <- hchart(gapminder::gapminder,
       "column",
       hcaes(x = year, y = lifeExp, size = pop),
       colorByPoint = TRUE)

hc |> hc_add_theme(hc_theme(chart = list(backgroundColor = 'red')))
```